# How to make top-bar like sublime top-bar using real CSS?

Tags: css

I want to make like this but my top bar is to different i dont know how to make like this

[image]

```css
.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
```

Comment: you mean triangle border?

Comment: yep like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ul list

```css
.open-file-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  top: var(--header-height);
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  color: white;
  color: var(--text-main-color)
}

.open-file-list li.tile {
  min-width: -webkit-min-content;
  min-width: -moz-min-content;
  min-width: min-content;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: inherit
}

.open-file-list li.tile::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #7eb4e2;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.3) perspective(0.5em) rotateX(5deg);
  height: 30px;
}

.open-file-list li.tile.text{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: inherit
}

.open-file-list li.tile.select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.open-file-list li.tile.notice::before {
  content: '♥';
  color: #00ff00;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 2.5px
}

.open-file-list li.tile.active {
  border-top: solid 2px #00ee00;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.open-file-list li.tile .file,.open-file-list li.tile .icon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-size: 14px;
  background-position: center;
  color: inherit
}
```

Comment: Please provide your html code also so that I can refer your code structure :).

Answer (score 2):

Please try following example. I think you can use or customize some value.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 70px;
  background: #f69ec4;
}

.tabs {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav,
.content {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #32557f;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  border-radius: .15em;
  border: .2em solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav > a {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .7em 2em .5em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 -.3em;
}
nav > a::before {
  border: .2em solid #fff;
}
nav a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  background: #7eb4e2;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.3) perspective(0.5em) rotateX(5deg);
}

nav a.active {
  z-index: 2;
}
nav a.active::before {
  background-color: #32557f;
  margin-bottom: -.08em;
}

.tab-left-right nav {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
.tab-left-right nav a::before {
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs tab-left-right">
  <nav>
    <a href="#content1">Tab1</a>
    <a href="#content2">Tab2</a>
    <a href="#content3">Tab3</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="content" id="content1">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: below this comment check it